# How can I modify a column in a table , adding CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to modify a column in a table by adding a CASE statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE GIAC
alter column President_Eligible varchar(3) as CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date_Election_President,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= 730 THEN 'NON' ELSE 'OUI' END
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

This is the table structure:

```
create table GIAC
(
    Nom_Giac varchar(50) primary key, 
    Raison_sociale varchar(20) not null,
    Ville varchar(20),
    Fax varchar(30),
    Adress varchar(50) not null,
    SiteWeb varchar(40),
    Nom_Prenom_President varchar(50) not null,
    President_Eligible varchar(3) as CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date_Election_President,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= 730 THEN 'NON' ELSE 'OUI' END,
    Tel_President varchar(30),
    EMAIL_President varchar(30),
    Nom_Prenom_Directeur varchar(50),
    Tel_Directeur varchar(30),
    EMAIL_Directeur varchar(30),
    Nom_Prenom_Contact varchar(50),
    Tel_Contact varchar(30),
    EMAIL_Contact varchar(30),  
    RIB_Fonct varchar(60) unique,
    RIB_Action varchar(60) unique 
)
```

Comment: Why you want to alter data? Since you are using same conditions to alter column, which you had already used during creating table.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but enough folks visiting over the years that could still help to give an answer. Two step process. Alter the table to add the field. Then update with a case statement. E.g.

```
alter table mytable add column new_field int;
update mytable  set new_field =
                (case
                when existing_field =1 then 1
                when existing_field =2  then 0
                when existing_field =0  then 0
                else null
                end);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid to specify the data type so it has to be:

```
President_Eligible  as CASE WHEN 1>2 THEN 'NON' ELSE 'OUI' END
```

Instead of

```
President_Eligible varchar(3) as CASE WHEN 1>2 THEN 'NON' ELSE 'OUI' END
```

Comment: i want to add it ? how can i ?

Comment: you mean like this : ALTER TABLE GIAC
alter column President_Eligible as CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date_Election_President,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= 730 THEN 'NON' ELSE 'OUI' END

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in order to change a computed column, you must DROP and re-CREATE the column.